# How to check if an input to a Bash script contains a 4 or more letter word from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have to test whether part of a String contains anywhere in it a 4 letter or more word from a given file (words.txt) and print whether it does or not. Here is my code so far:

```
if [[ grep -q *"$Str"* words.txt ]]; then
   echo Yes
else
   echo No
```

I am not able to match it correctly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

So, I have a large file with random words and I need to test if a string I input has a substring of any word within that file
For example: If I input the string "ehhelloef" and words.txt has the word "hello" in it, it needs to detect. Additionally, I only need to test words from words.txt that are longer than 4 lletters

Comment: Are the words in this file all separated by line?

Comment: Yes. It is just a large file with many words 1 per line and if the given string has one of those words anywhere in it the program should notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[[` [extended test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands) is intended for use with specific [operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) and not commands.

---

The following `awk` command should work:

```
awk -vcheck="$Str" '(check ~ $1 && length($1) > 3) {found="yes"} END {if (found=="yes") {print "yes"} else {print "no"}}' words.txt
```

This will check if each word in the file is a substring of the input string and that the word's length is greater than 3.  If it is the `found` variable will be set to yes.  When `awk` finishes with the file it will check if `found` equals yes and if so it will print `yes`, otherwise it will print `no`

---

If you **need** this in a shell if construct to do something other than print yes/no you can replace the print statements with exit ones like so:

```
if awk -vcheck="$Str" '(check ~ $1 && length($1) > 3) {found="yes"} END {if (found=="yes") {exit 0} else {exit 1}}' words.txt
then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

Comment: This works for checking the file, I was messing around with awk earlier but I couldn't get it into an if statement that works and returns a yes or no and returns . Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you simply want a yes/no if it contains the word and don't want to see output?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm looking for but the code above works perfectly, I was trying to do it with awk but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: @Jean: does my latest update work for you?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was trying to do. It's a lot more work than it seemed. Thank you for that!

Comment: It would be slightly more efficient I think if (a la `grep -q`) you exited on the first match e.g. `(check ~ $1 && length($1) > 3) {found=1; exit} END {if (found) exit(0); else exit(1)}`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

1. extract the 4-or-more letter words from `words.txt`
2. pass the result as a "file" to `grep -Ff` so as to do a fixed-string match against the variable's contents:

Ex. making use of a bash *process substitution* and *here string*

```
grep -Fqf <(grep '....' words.txt) <<< "$str" && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```